# Cordova Local Notification on moto E (4.4.4 stock)

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, ionic-framework

does someone have problems on Moto E with notifications ?
currently working on project that involve Cordova Local Notification plugin, that works just perfect on 4.3 (alcatel one touch, nokia x2) 5.0 (nexus 7) 4.4 (nokia x2 cyanogenmod), but nothing on Moto E (stock 4.4) 
building with latest android SDK, cordova(5.1.1), ionic(1.6.4)

checked permissions with:

```
plugin.notification.local.hasPermission(function (granted) {
 console.log('Permission has been granted: ' + granted);
});
```

No errors in console(answers 'true')

Scheduling notifications with:

```
var alarmTime = new Date().getMinutes();
  $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
  id: "1",
  text: "xxx",
  title: "www",
  at: alarmTime
});
```

Check notification status (notify with delay) with:

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.isScheduled("1").then(function(isScheduled) {
  alert("Notification status: " + isScheduled);
});
```

And there is everything ok too ...